# How to vary information in different table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Using several tutorials I have created a successful Table View Application App. The first two cells I have only inserted a picture and information into the cell. However, now I want to insert videos, web view, and a map view in three of the cells, is that possible ?

I have already created a video, web view and map view app on a different Xcode project and now I don't know how I can "insert" them into my table view application app.

I would really be happy and appreciate your help! :))

Cheers Filip
(If you want to have a closer look at my project I would have no problem sending you my Xcode project)

[The first two cells I have edited information into,however I don't know how I can insert Videos-Unsere Videos...... Web page- Unsere Webseite Map View- Wo Sie uns finden..... into the three other cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS3C3.png)

[Main Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWlfe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Good thing about `tableView` it can be as more variable as you want it to be. To Add `UITableViewCell` of ur choice, first configure the `cell` (using story board or code), then do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {//this line can vary according to your requierment
        case 0:
            //RETURN image cell
            break;
        case 1:
            //RETURN image cell
            break;
        case 2:
            //RETURN Video player cell
            break;
        case 3:
            //RETURN webview cell
            break;
        case 4:
            //RETURN any other cell
            break;

        default:
            //RETURN default cell
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hello rptwsthi, 
Thank you for your answer. 
I am still a bit confused what to do. Can I send you my Xcode project ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class Costtom From UItableViewCell and import headefile this class to primary class and use class costom for create UITableViewCell for example:

PriceTableViewCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PriceTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
     @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *nameString;
     @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *titleString;
     @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *priceString;
     @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *dateString;
     @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *ownerString;
@end
```

PriceTableViewCell.m:

```
#import "PriceTableVIewCell.h"
@impliment PriceTableViewCell

@end
```

and PrimaryClass.m:

```
 #import "PriceTableViewCell.h"
 ....//code here
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = (PriceTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     if(cell==nil){
          cell =  [[PriceTableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     }
     ...//code here
}
```

Comment: Hello afshin, Thank you for your answer. I am still a bit confused what to do. Can I send you my Xcode project ? Would help me really really much...

Comment: Gmail: moosamir68@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you so much. Have you received my email?